# Make Bootstrap drop-down submenu stay open and highlighted when on page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I’m trying to have a Bootstrap drop-down submenu highlighted and stay open when navigated to that submenu page. I’m using sb-admin v2 as the basis for a project, http://usebootstrap.com/preview/sb-admin-2/index.html .

Here’s a section of the left-hand menu structure:

```
Dashboard
Charts
    Flot
    Morris.js
Tables
Forms
…
```

Collapsed it looks like this:

```
Dashboard
Charts
Tables
Forms
…
```

When on the Flot page (flot.html), I’d like the drop-down Charts menu to stay open with Flot submenu highlighted. As it is now, the drop-down menus collapse when navigating to any of the drop-down sub-menu pages. I need them to stay open. I’m not sure how to post the code or where to start.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: start pasting the html, css and js needed to reproduce at least the basic functionality

Comment: If you can create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) showing your issue. or just use the built in snippet section when editing your question.

Comment: I created https://codepen.io/mrfisherman2010/pen/QaQQVd but I can't get the functionality right. By default is should load with the Flot Charts and Morris.js Charts submenus collapsed. I'm not linking to a css or js correctly.